# approach for multilingual testing using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, multilingual

I am new to automation.My project is a multilingual website.Wanted to know how best can I automate it using selenium webdriver & Testng.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate a multilingual website using `Selenium Webdriver`, there are few basic things you need to keep in mind:

1. If you are using locators which is using any textual content like
   `text()`, `starts-with()` e.t.c - You need to handle them separately
   for each language.
2. If you are using any `text` based validations, you need to take care of them as well.

I would suggest you to create a localization file for each language and load them according to the language you are using. In that localization file you can handle things like `locators and assertions which uses text()`